# How can I add a Play Framework 2.x module's managed code to Eclipse dependencies?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I made an eclipse project for my application using eclipsify. Then I added the code at `appHome/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main` to the dependency list and everything works fine except for the code that calls modules. It seems I am missing some classes that belong to them. Where can I find them? What is the place where Play places the code generated for those modules?

I am currently running Play 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Jose!
You should not change any code at target folders. This folders are generated automatically from your source folders. 
So, just try to remove target folders from the project, and then use compile and eclipsify again.
Hope it would help.

Comment: No, It is not because I would change the code in the target folder. I just want Eclipse to recognize it so that the references to it are not considered errors anymore. All code is recognized after following instructions from playframework.org but the code belonging to plug-ins.